IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: While accessing s3 bucket data through PySpark
I am trying to read a parquet through PySpark in a Jupyter notebook.
sc = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("classifier")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key",key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A")

sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().setInt("fs.s3a.connection.maximum", 100)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.buffer.dir", "/var/tmp/spark")

sql = SQLContext(sc)

spark = SparkSession(sc)
#sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate() 
path="s3a://s3test-dev/classifier/final_sample.parquet"
df=spark.read.parquet(path)

I get this error message below:
Illegal character in authority at index 8: https://Cloud Object Storage - Amazon S3  - AWS.

read the hadoop s3a documentation and work out how to configure it. you are never going to make progress otherwise. Especially if all you are doing is copy-and-paste of other people's posts and answers.

Thank you @stevel - Did that already! I believe this is something to do with java connection, because, even after changing the path to any other bucket, I get the same error!

its a configuration problem. I'm just being ruthless and telling you to RTFM as you haven't done that or looked at the error message in any detail to identify what the problem is or where. sorry to be less helpful but you need to start doing this.

I added a full summary. Hopefully the next time someone tries to set fs.s3a.endpoint to a random string they will make better progress. There is limit we can do in the codebase itself.

@pnv having read the answer, and assuming it is correct, can you tick it to show it was accepted. thanks

The configuration is broken, containing a mix of superfluous and pathologically bad settings.
Going through them.
fs.s3a.impl
Names the class bonded to the s3a URL.
This is completely superfluous. It is set by default in core-default.xml in hadoop-common JAR.
indicates use of stack overflow articles rather than reading the documentation.
Recommendation: Cut
fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl
See above.
com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4
Possibly a reference to the java system property needed on hadoop 2.6 to tell the AWS SDK how to talk AWS regions deployed since 2014 (frankfurt, london). It hasn't been needed for almost a decade and if passed down as a hadoop configuration option
is completely ignored by everything.
Recommendation: Cut
fs.s3a.connection.maximum
Size of http connection pool.
Recommendation: leave alone until operations fail with "timeout waiting for connection from the connection pool"
fs.s3a.buffer.dir
Temporary directory used when writing data. Default is hadoop.tmp.dir, which picks up the system property java.tmp.dir
Recommendation: Best left alone.
fs.s3a.access.key
Account ID. Not a critical secret, but still something you don't want to share too widely.
Recommendation: manage your use of this carefully.
fs.s3a.secret.key
The secret part of your AWS login. It is absolutely critical that this is never shared; Putting it into any form of SCM system is very risky.
Recommendation: Keep out of your source entirely.
Spark will pick up the AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY environment variables and set the hadoop configuration options from them. This is probably the simplest option.
fs.s3a.endpoint
The S3 Service endpoint you are interacting with
This MUST be one of

blank. uses the default s3.amazonaws.com.
A region specific S3 endpoint, such as s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com.
Saves the overhead of an HTTP request and a 302/400 redirect on the instantiation of the client.
a hostname, possibly fully qualified. Needed when talking to a third-party store.

What it MUST NOT BE is a string like "Cloud Object Storage - Amazon S3  - AWS "
That is
-not a valid URL
-not a hostname
When the S3A connector tries to pause the option it Well because it is not a URL.
It will inform the user that is not URL by providing an informative error message
Illegal character in authority at index 8: https://Cloud Object Storage - Amazon S3  - AWS.

There's not really much that S3A connector can do here.
However, developers on the project, expect the users of the connector to understand the term "endpoint",
and know what a well-formed URL is as well as a fully qualified domain name.
If you feel it was not helpful enough, Please submit a github pull request With new tests
and a declaration of which S3 endpoint you did a full run of the hadoop-aws integration tests
testing s3a.
Regarding your own configuration:
Recommend: cut this completely unless using a third-party endpoint, in which case set it to a valid value.
Summary
To summarise then

Cut every single configuration option apart from the access and secret key
Consider moving those to environment variables for security reasons.
Start with the S3A documentation
over Stack Overflow posts, especially old ones. It doesn't matter how many votes they have: If they are 10 years old they are out of date.


Thanks for the detailed answer @stevel, though my problem is unresolved.

well, if fs.s3a.endpoint is still as broken as it is in the example. it never will be.
